# java.lang.ClassCastException: CustomAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ArrayAdapter In Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter, baseadapter, listadapter

I got the above-mentioned error when I try to create a custom adapter class in Kotlin

Source code

**MainActivity.kt**

```
 var adapterC:CustomAdapter = CustomAdapter(this,Statearray)
 spinnerState.adapter=adapterC
```

**CustomAdapter.kt**

```
class CustomAdapter(val activity: Activity,val array:JSONArray) : BaseAdapter(), ListAdapter
{
    lateinit var ItemName: TextView

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
    var view=convertView
    if (view == null)
        view = activity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinnerlayout, null)
    try {

        ItemName = view?.findViewById(R.id.ItemName) as TextView
        val obj = array.getJSONObject(position)
        ItemName.setText(obj.getString("Name"))
        view.setTag(obj.getString("Id"))

    } catch ( e:JSONException) {
        Log.e("At Custom Class",e.toString())
    }

    return view
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): JSONObject {
    return array.optJSONObject(position)
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    var jsonObject=getItem(position)
    return jsonObject.optLong("id")
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return array.length()
}

}
```

Need Help I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: where are you setting the adapter? post that code

Comment: your `CustomAdapter` does not extend `ArrayAdapter`. To understand: Elephant can't be casted to a bird because it does not extend the bird. While eagle can be casted to a bird because it **does** extend the bird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figure it out.. the problem was, iwas using a spinner library which only support     ArrayAdapter

the library that i used was

```
com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1
```

it only support arrayadapter

Comment: have you implemented data binding using this library?

Answer (score 1):

[**`ClassCastException`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a
>   subclass of which it is not an instance.

**FYI**

You added **`Multiple Adapter`**. Remove 2nd One.

**<s>Don't</s>**

```
class CustomAdapter(val activity: Activity,val array:JSONArray) : BaseAdapter(), ListAdapter
```

**Do**

```
class CustomAdapter(context: Context,var arrayLIST: ArrayList<Response>) : BaseAdapter() {
```

**DEMO**

```
var arrayLIST: ArrayList<Response>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        arrayLIST=ArrayList()
        val jsonObj = ("[{\"Id\":\"35\",\"Name\":\"Kerala\"},{\"Id\":\"36\",\"Name\":\"Tamilnadu\"}]")
        val jo = JSONArray(jsonObj)
        val num = 0 until jo.length()
        for (i in num) {
            val loanObj = jo.getJSONObject(i)
            val Id      = loanObj.getString("Id")
            val Name    = loanObj.getString("Name")

            arrayLIST!!.add(Response(Id,Name))


        }
      var adapterC:CustomAdapter = CustomAdapter(this@MainActivity,arrayLIST)
```

**Response.kt**

```
data class Response
(
        @SerializedName("id")               val id               : String,
        @SerializedName("name")            val  name             : String
)
```

**NOTE**

Make sure add,

```
   implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but I am not using a recyclerview here. it is spinner ... Don't get me wrong.. can I use recycler view adapter with a spinner?

Comment: @AjithMadhu https://github.com/bidrohi/KotlinListView/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/bidyut/example/kotlinlistview/ListViewActivity.kt

Comment: @AjithMadhu Did you follow above links? By the way show us `Statearray`

Comment: [{"Id":"35","Name":"Kerala"},{"Id":"36","Name":"Tamilnadu"}]

Comment: @AjithMadhu Through loop send  `JSONObject`  Data not `Array`

Comment: Sir my requirement is to show the district when a user selects a particular state. for that I created this array... the logic was to create a custom adapter and set the id as tag to the view.. so that I can get it, when user select a particular state

Comment: @AjithMadhu You should create a MODEL class which holds ID,NAME

Comment: @AjithMadhu Kindly check my answer

Comment: thank you very much for spending your valuable time for me... and i am extremely sorry for making this kind of silly mistakes.... thanx ..

Comment: @AjithMadhu No problem. Sometimes it happen!